# Ambari metrics Thrift Server

Tags: thrift, ambari

I installed Apache Ambari 2.6.2.2 and I deployed two services: Hbase and AMS.

For Hbase I started thrift server, from UI I can see metrics for this server (http://localhost:9095/jmx), but it seems that AMS it does not collect them. In AMS I can see only Hbase metrics.

My question is how can I collect the metrics from Thrift Server in AMS and if there is any Grafana dashboard already configured for this type of metrics?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built solutions in Ambari so far.

I ended up creating a custom script, which does two things:

- pulls the metrics from Thrift Server (http://thrift_server:9095/jmx)
- pushes these metrics to Ambari Metrics Collector (POST http://ambari-metrics-collector:6188/ws/v1/timeline/metrics, see for reference [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Metrics+Collector+API+Specification)

After, I created a custom dashboard in Grafana, that displays the following metrics:

- JVM Memory
- Coalescing increments
- Requests time for thrift one/thrift two.